# Change background-color of button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a HTML webPage, I use a button and I need to change his background-color on mouseover using a javascript function.
Here is the code.

```
<button onmouseover="funzione(this)">BTN</button>
<script>
    funzione(x){
        x.style.background-color=#ffffff;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: css property are always camelized in js

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you need get handler to element `x` e.g.:

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
```

but you should do this with CCS:

```
button{
    background-color: yellow;
}

button:hover{
    background-color: lime;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic. You're missing keyword `function`, and with that style of accessing properties, you need to use camel case. Finally, wrap the color hex within quotes.

```js
function funzione(x){
   x.style.backgroundColor= '#ffffff';
}
```

```html
<button onmouseover="funzione(this)">BTN</button>
```

The recommended way is use CSS in production, but if you're just into JavaScript and want to explore, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want in js:

```html
<button onmouseover="set_color(this)">BTN</button>
<script>
function set_color(x){
 x.style.backgroundColor='red';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function funzione(x){
  x.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
```

```html
<button onmouseover = "funzione(this)">BTN</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply in CSS, its easy, efficient and less code.

```
<style type="text/css">
.myHoverButton:hover { background-color: #ffffff; }
</style>

<button id="button1" class="myHoverButton">
```